# Suspending a Mini Zip Wire from a Garage Beams - Structural and Clearance Questions

Tags: joists, bolts

I am planning to build a mini zip wire for my son in our garage. The use case for this for him to safely practice grinds and jumps without falling and injuring himself.

A similar approach has been used by another skater here: https://www.northwestskater.com/harness.html which shows a skate harness in use.

Here is a mockup of how it would look in our garage.

[image: Zip Wire Mockup]

The skater would be able to jump/slide along the rail at the bottom of the image, while using the zipwire attached between two points attached to beams in the garage roof.

Building the zip wire assembly and harness should be straightforward.

The issue I need advice on is how to suspend the assembly from the garage joists. These are 6x2s, 3.125 metres long (see image).

[image: garage beams]

The problem is load bearing and suspension clearance. I thought of sistering the affected joists and inserting an eyebolt with a backing plate at each end to attach the assembly.

But the problem with this approach is that it doesn't allow clearance for the zip wire and cable trolley to move underneath the beams.

The approach I am currently considering has been used to suspend punchbags from similar garage joists. I saw this image in another thread:

[image: suspension point]

I was thinking of doing something similar, but also allowing the eyebolt to protrude further out from the bottom, to allow clearance for the zip wire trolley to move freely.

Does any see any structural issues with suspending this kind of assembly in this way? The load bearing will be to catch my son if he trips or falls from the rail below, rather than sustained hanging from the zip wire. It's only intended as a 'safety net' if he falls.

Any advice welcome.

EDIT

The following image shows the importance of suspending the attachment points for either end of the zip wire below the level of the joists, to enable the zip wire trolley to roll freely along the length of the steel wire.

[image]

Comment: That's a brutal looking game of hangman in your first image! :D (Honestly, that's what it looked like, but the drawing as a whole is very informative - thanks for providing it, so many don't bother!) The first image in your linked page shows the line attached to the ceiling at the end and at the wall and no other apparent attachments until, presumably, the other end of the cable. You, however are talking about a "rail" (sounds like at the ceiling, am I reading wrong?). Maybe a somewhat more detailed drawing in addition to the hangman sketch?

Comment: The rail is on the floor for the skateboarding, @FreeMan Visible in the left half of the picture.

Comment: That's what I initially thought @Ecnerwal, but reading through I wasn't sure. I'm still confused, though, what the "punching bag mounting block" is for and how that's going to interfere with the trolley. One mount at each end (OK, two - 1 to the wall and a 2nd to the ceiling) and the trolley rolls between them.

Comment: The PBMB is an example found elsewhere that's inspiring a modified version of itself as a possible solution. Grab more coffee!

Comment: Sorry, yes to clarify, the rail the skater will ride is set on the floor. The zip wire cable to which the skater is attached runs parallel to it along the ceiling, attached to two eye bolts at either end. The skater wears a harness with an attachment via a carabiner to the zip wire trolley on the cable. Ideally, they should feel its presence until they fall or trip, in which case their fall is arrested through their attachment to the zip wire.

Comment: In the second pic, there is a metal rail attached to the lintel above the garage door. This is part of a broken garage door opening mechanism, and is unconnected with the zip wire.

Comment: There's also the option of using roller tracks for sliding doors like this - https://www.mcmaster.com/ceiling-tracks/roller-track-for-doors-6/.  Might be more expensive than cable, but would be easy to securely install and be very secure.

Comment: That makes more sense @Ecnerwal & Incertus. I was thinking the blocking with eye-bolts was to run along the entire length of the ceiling with the wire running through all the eye-bolts. That would be quite a difficult engineering challenge, and that's what was trowing me. For something like that, you'd have to have a cable-car/roller coaster type suspension system and that would be... out of scope!

Comment: @JPhi1618 Your idea seems to be a better solution. You should write it up as an actual answer.

Comment: @gnicko As I wrote that comment someone else was [writing an answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/265634/43874) that included it.

Comment: Do you have a finished spaced about this garage?   A finished space above a garage reduces the load you can hang from the ceiling.   I suspect you do not as there is no insulation, but something to check.   In the south, I've seen garage attics converted into "bonus" rooms with nothing on the garage ceiling.

Comment: I looked at the example.  In that example, they have secured the wire to the wall and the joist.  That would split the loads and control forces in 2 different directions.

Answer (score 6):

If the cable is meant to catch your son falling you have to think about the forces of that.  It's not fixed weight such as of a punching bag, or of your son (e.g. there are lots of questions here about installing chin-up bars).   If he begins falling and is caught after attaining some speed, the force on the cable will be high.

On top of that, the position of your son along the cable will cause various different forces on the joists.

Assuming the cable goes front to  back of the garage, across the joists.

If you just attach to joists with screw eyes, even if you sister them, and if he falls in the middle of the run, the force on the screws will want to tear them out the sides of the joists, and may just do that.  I don't know how to calculate that and I wouldn't want to rely on it.

I like the picture of the block across two joists.   Instead of using a screw eye, run a bolt through the TOP of the block, and hang a chain between both sides of the bolt.  This avoids the problem of the screw eye tearing out of the block and gains you maximum strength in all directions from the block and the two joists.

Even better, screw a rail across all the joists and use a carriage to suspend a cable that will always hang vertically from the rail. This spreads the load across more joists and keeps the forces uniform if he falls from different positions along the cable.    You could use commercial door hardware for this or perhaps buy "strut channel" from a local store (to avoid high shipping costs) and buy "trolley for strut channel" online.   You'd have to shop around for the most heavy duty combination of trolley and channel that you can source easily.

Comment: I posted a comment above as you were writing this, so [here](https://www.mcmaster.com/ceiling-tracks/roller-track-for-doors-6/) is a possible track to use, and a carriage would look [like this](https://www.mcmaster.com/ceiling-tracks/track-rollers-5/).  Track would be a better solution for sure.

Comment: I very much like the garage door track idea. I was thinking of a small I-beam. I guess that's essentially what the garage door track is.

Comment: Aluminum I beam would be nice but may be expensive?   I added to the answer a suggestion using strut channel and easily sourced trolleys designed for that.

Comment: I'd not even considered this as an approach, but I think it could work, definitely. And it might work even better than a zip wire, because there wouldn't be any slack, so the roller could move unimpeded. If I screwed the rail to the joists, would the standard support brackets be enought to take the load of an unexpected fall? https://www.mcmaster.com/ceiling-tracks/roller-track-for-doors-6/

Comment: IMO --- buy strut channel from a big hardware store, it has holes in the back, screw it directly to the joists with lag screws. Experiment to ensure the trolley clears the screw heads.  [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ottY2IXZA_Q) purely for amusement is a guy who takes DIY a step too far by building his own trolley from spat out chewing gum (or something like that)

Comment: I'm a big fan of McMaster Carr shopping porn but I think buying a 10 foot steel rail on line will add shipping costs that you could spend on other things.  The rail is easily found locally.  Go see what's in stock at an orange or blue store near you (or a better hardware store in your town if you have one) and before buying the rail, find a trolley that will fit.

Comment: @Incertus The least expensive galvanized steel option has a _working_ capacity of 400lbs.  Since the slack in the line is minimized compared to a cable, and the components can handle well above their working loads, I think it would be fine.  I'd probably order a shorter piece of track and test it out first.

Comment: @jay613 Agree - those are nice examples to pull from an expansive catalog, but I'm sure you can find them locally with no shipping.

Comment: "the force on the screws will want to tear them out the sides of the joists" -- my intuition says that the static or dynamic vertical load on the middle of the zip-line will be transformed into far higher horizontal loads on the wire's attachment points, and therefore the force on the screws (or whatever) and beams could be surprisingly high.  Is that correct?

Comment: @WayneConrad yes we're saying the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Install blocking, similar to the punching bag example provided, that is deeper or offset and thus protrudes beyond the bottom of the joists.

Fasten to joists with end nails or end screws (use structural screws).

Hangers -as in the example- will not be possible due to the desired protrusion, and are an odd way to overkill blocking anyway.

For extra strength install several such blocking members as a sandwich/laminate (fastened into joist and fastened together like a laminar beam).

Optionally install a further piece of **strapping lumber** flat against the protruding lip, i.e. the block edges, on the side of the zip line. This is piece is parallel to the joist and may offer a larger surface area for mounting screws, without concerns about the lamination seams.

If you space the blocking pieces, rather than laminate them, you can use **through-bolts** to attach the cable mounting plate, since you'll have access behind the strapping lumber.

[image]

The strapping should be fastened with screws not nails. Use at least two blocking members, and drop the blocking sufficiently to allow for 2 screws per block through the strapping, each 1in vertically apart. Use structural screws or lag screws for their increased bending strength and thread grab.

You can also first install deeper strapping lumber against the joist on the blocking side, and then add the blocking. This eliminates the risk of strapping pull out.

[image]

You can add further non-protruding blocking in the adjacent joist bay, above the dashed red zip line. Install it staggered so that you can end-nail/screw both sets of blocking.

Comment: I did think of using brackets, and cutting the block to create an underhanging protrusion (think of a fat 'T' shape). But I like your approach 

Comment: I might suggest using blocking between the two joists where the cable will attach _and_ between the next two joists toward the center of the cable span. This will spread any falling load over 6 joists (3 at each end) instead of just 4 (2 at each end).

Comment: @FreeMan yes I was thinking that too, additional blocking above the dashed red zip line in my drawing